# how can I make many changes to css on hover state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make div display on hover, but I want it to hover over div already present instead of pushing present div down. I think z-index will help but this does not work. can anyone give me a good tip?

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#services-skills').hover(function(){
        $('#services-skills').css('position','relative');
        $('.service-info').css("display","inline");
        $('#intro').css('position','relative');
        $('#intro').css("z-index","-3");
    },
    function(){
        $('.service-info').css("display","none");
    }
    );
});
```

to see entire code sample please click here

http://jsfiddle.net/rU4pn/

Comment: It's not a z-index issue. You need to make it have position absolute or use negative margins (not so great)

Comment: you don't have to use a script for your desired behavior. all of that can be achieved with smart CSS selectors and the use of the `:hover` pseudo selector.

Comment: @avrahamcool Hi, will this work in ie to?

Comment: yes, those pseudo selectors are part of the CSS spec. create a working fiddle of the style changes you want with a script (after you'll find the issue you're trying to solve), and I will show you how to transform it to a pure CSS version. **Notice:** the layout has to be simple enough (kind of like your old example) for it to work. so we can target elements with CSS selectors. right now you have a DOM typo in you Fiddle. elements that will be affected by the hover has to be nested within the hovered element, or the single element who comes right after it.

Comment: so, do you have an updated fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have something overlay something else you'll need to use absolute positoning in CSS. The key to getting that to line up with something else (rather than the page) is to have relative (or absolute) positioning on it's parent element and then set it's top and left positions to the offset you want from the parent element.

Z-index will decide the order of items (front to back) on screen for absolutely positioned items, with the lowest numbers set at the back and higher numbers at the front, however remember that any item will not display at a higher z-index level than it's parent item as it's contained within it.